# not able to find shared library files in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, shared-libraries, google-colaboratory

I am working on deep learning architecture which uses shared library files which are built on the local system, now my computer is not having space to run my code, so I want to run my code in colab. To run on colab, the colab is not showing my shared libraries file which I am trying to build on google colab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount your GDrive and copy the files from Colab cloud working directory

```
!mv /content/filename /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/
```